# Adding/Installing vim plugins

Tags: vim, plugins

I am trying to add Ack grep [plugin](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) .After downloading the file I unzipped the file and copied ack.vim from the plugin directory to .vim/bundle
However when I launch a gvim and do something like this

```
:Ack foo
```

I get Ack is not an editor command
Any suggestions on how I can install this plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a plugin manager like [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim). After following the instructions on the Vundle webpage to install it you can add `Plugin 'mileszs/ack.vim'` in the list of plugins in your `.vimrc`. after simply `:BundleInstall` and it will automatically install.

Comment: I already have pathogen thats why i am dumping the .vim in bundle

Answer (score 0):

> I already have pathogen thats why i am dumping the .vim in bundle

What's the point of installing a tool like pathogen if you don't bother learning how to use it?

You are supposed to put **the whole directory** in `~/.vim/bundle/`:

```
~/.vim/bundle/
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/autoload/
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/autoload/ack.vim
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/doc/
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/doc/ack_quick_help.txt
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/doc/ack.txt
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/ftplugin/
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/ftplugin/qf.vim
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/plugin/
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim-master/plugin/ack.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Ack on your system first.

For example, on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install Ack
```